# ¿De dónde viene "tontolaba"?

Tags: etimología, insultos

La palabra *tontolaba* es, [según parece](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-viene-la-expresion-tontolaba/), un insulto proveniente de la expresión "tonto del haba", usada para designar a aquel a quien le toca el haba en el roscón de Reyes y, por tanto, le toca pagarlo. No viene en el diccionario de la RAE, pero ha hecho algunas apariciones curiosas incluso en el cine: en la película de *Ponyo en el acantilado* en un momento dado uno de los personajes pronuncia muy despacio la palabra "oobaka" ("grandísimo tonto" en japonés) y el traductor, viendo el esquema vocal "o-o-a-a" y por mantener la coherencia con el movimiento de los labios, decidió traducirla (muy acertadamente según mi opinión) como "tontolaba".

En el CORDE aparecen algunos casos, siendo el más antiguo de 1984:

> *[...] se desternillaba de risa el tío Jotero criticando al tontolaba y jactancioso de Cristóbal el Caguetas [...].*
>
> Andrés Berlanga, "La gaznápira", 1984 (España).

En la hemeroteca de la BNE el texto más antiguo que la usa es de 1975, y en Ngram encuentro uno de 1968:

> *[...] les dijo el tontolaba ese, que yo era un muerto de hambre [...].*
>
> José Alberto Martín Morales, "Carril de un cuerpo", 1968 (España).

Sin embargo, la duda que me entra es que si la expresión proviene de ahí, en algún momento anterior a 1968 tendría que haber quedado registrado algún uso de "tonto del haba", pero no encuentro ninguno. Hay algunos en la hemeroteca pero son de 1986 el más reciente, y ya me cuestiono si no habrá sido al revés y "tonto del haba" se ha formado desde "tontolaba".

Pregunto pues: ¿realmente viene "tontolaba" de "tonto del haba"? ¿Es posible encontrar registros que confirmen este origen? ¿O hay alguna otra explicación para el origen de la expresión?

Nota: como dice *murder of crows* en comentarios, se usa también la forma *tontolava*. Sin embargo, solo encuentro casos escritos así en la hemeroteca de la BNE y en textos a partir del 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el *Fichero general* de la RAE hay algunas fichas sobre la palabra, que demuestran que en 1952 ya se usaba la palabra al menos en la región de Pamplona. En una de ellas, del *Vocabulario navarro* de [José María Iribarren](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mar%C3%ADa_Iribarren), se puede leer lo siguiente:

> TONTOLABA. Dícese de la persona muy tonta, muy imbécil: «Eres un tontolaba». Alfonso Reta comenta que esta voz proviene, según comunicación por escrito que recibió del Dr. Lapesa, de «tonto (del) haba», con posible influencia del «rey de la faba», con que se designaba en la edad media al hombre que por sorteo (de ahí «la faba», el haba empleada para sortear) tenía que hacer burlescamente de rey en una diversión.

Así pues, parece que sí, que "tontolaba" viene de "tonto del haba", aunque no me queda claro si esto tiene algo que ver con el roscón de Reyes o con algún otro tipo de sorteo. El doctor Lapesa del que habla el texto es [Rafael Lapesa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafael_Lapesa), filólogo y miembro de la RAE.

Y por cierto, me acabo de dar cuenta de que la expresión original sí viene en el diccionario, aunque un poco escondida:

> **[del haba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JuuLons#DJf4EIk)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. U. para intensificar la expresividad de la voz *tonto*, a la que sigue.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es todo más prosaico. Proviene de una enfermedad, el fabismo, debido a la deficiencua del enzima glucosa-6-fosfato deshidrogenasa (G6PD), que puede provocar como efecto colateral un retraso mental en quien la padece.

Comment: Intereseante idea, pero el retraso mental **no** es característico del fabismo (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficiencia_de_glucosa-6-fosfato_deshidrogenasa)